# Operator error while trying to change the value of a key in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, operators

I am not able to understand why is **line 22** an **operator error**

My Code:

```
#let's produce 30 aliens

aliens=[]
for alien_number in range(30) :
    new_alien = {'colour':'green','points':5}
    aliens.append(new_alien)

#changing asome aliens to another type
for alien_x in aliens[:3] :
    alien_x['colour'] = 'yellow'
    alien_x['points'] = 10
print(aliens[:5])

print(f"no, of aliens is {len(aliens)}")

# game speeds up/ level up
for alien_x in aliens :
    if alien_x['colour'] == 'yellow' :
        alien_x['colour'] = 'red' and alien_x['points'] = alien_x['points'] + 10

    elif alien_x['colour'] == 'green' :
        alien_x['colour'] = 'yellow' and alien_x['points'] = alien_x['points'] + 10

print(aliens)
```

error:

```
alien_x['colour'] = 'yellow' and alien_x['points'] = alien_x['points'] + 10
                    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

intended purpose:

1. first set generates a nested list of 30 dictonaries
2. then we change first three aliens to yellow
3. we print the first 5 aliens
4. now change all yellow aliens to red and green aliens to yellow
5. print all aliens

Comment: Remove the ```and``` and move the line following the ```and``` to the next line

Comment: Just separate that into two separate lines instead of trying to do it in one statement with `and`?!

Comment: May I please know why this is happening? I mean the method with "and" statement should work just fine too according to me.

Comment: no, and operator is used in condtional statements, not to make two assignments at the same time. Just make it in two lines. I would recommend looking at some python tutorial or so to understand the basics.

Comment: Assignments are *statements* in Python, you cannot chain statements with `and`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `and` during updating the `dictionary` alien_x

**Correction Made:**

```
for alien_x in aliens :
    if alien_x['colour'] == 'yellow' :
        alien_x['colour'] = 'red'
        alien_x['points'] = alien_x['points'] + 10

    elif alien_x['colour'] == 'green' :
        alien_x['colour'] = 'yellow'
        alien_x['points'] = alien_x['points'] + 10
```

**Output**

```
[{'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 10}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 10}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 10}, {'colour': 'green', 'points': 5}, {'colour': 'green', 'points': 5}]
no, of aliens is 30
[{'colour': 'red', 'points': 20}, {'colour': 'red', 'points': 20}, {'colour': 'red', 'points': 20}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}, {'colour': 'yellow', 'points': 15}]
```